# React Native Fingerprint capture

Tags: ios, authentication, react-native, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am working on a React-Native web-based application and I want to create a new style of authentication. 

here what I hope to do: - 

I want to scan the user Fingerprint and save it to my database, then instead of giving me username and password. 

He just uses his fingerprint and it will login. 

so, is there any library or anything to help me scanning the fingerprint id and get its value to be saved? 

it is critical for me please HELP!

Comment: On iOS you use the Local Authentication framework.  You cannot capture fingeprints, but this framework will prompt the user to authenticate biometrical (fingerprint or face) and tell you whether a valid biometric authentication occurred.  You cannot distinguish between enrolled fingers

Comment: @ahmed shaltout do you find any solution...?

Comment: I think this will solve your issue. Let me know if it works. https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics

Comment: @TorikulAlam actually not

Comment: @beck no it didn't

Answer (score 0):

for ios you need to use Touch ID and,
here is good example  you can implement like that

http://blog.theodo.fr/2018/04/add-touch-id-react-native-app/

give specific error so people can help more .

Comment: The answer mentioned there, they use the touch id to authenticate the user locally, they ask the phone to authenticate the user to open the app.
I don't want to do it like this.
I want to get the value of the touch id and keep it on my server and authenticate the user myself next time.
Got it?

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.